# mysql - a SELECT that returns the highest 'views' and a specific id's 'views'

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write a single query that can return two rows, one specified in a WHERE clause and the other the highest in the table.

For example.

```
Table_1
-row_id
-views
-content
```

Is there a query which can combine the following:

```
SELECT views FROM Table_1 WHERE row_id = 10

SELECT MAX(views) FROM Table_1
```

or is two queries my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don think it is possible using technically a single query; However, you can use UNION operator

```
SELECT views FROM Table_1 WHERE row_id = 10

UNION

SELECT MAX(views) FROM Table_1
```

Comment: is a UNION more efficient that two separate queries?

Comment: hmmm... I personally think that Union will be 'slightly' better then sending two queries;

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(views) FROM Table_1) as max_view, views 
FROM Table_1 
WHERE row_id = 10
```

Each row would have the same `max_view` value in it.  I'm not sure what effect this query would have on performance with a large number of rows, however.

Comment: `(SELECT MAX(views) FROM Table_1) AS max` !

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION statement:

```
SELECT views FROM Table_1 WHERE row_id = 10 
UNION 
SELECT MAX(views) FROM Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two rows, one with the selected row and the other with the row with the highest view.

SELECT *
FROM Table_1 
WHERE row_id = 10 OR views = (SELECT MAX(views) FROM Table_1 LIMIT 1) 
SORT BY row_id = 10 DESC

Comment: Only trying to help! Down voting without an explanation is not decent.